# Run Flask application with Jython

Tags: python, flask, jython

I want to run a Flask application with Jython, but I am not able to find anything. Is it possible to combine Flask and Jython? I know Django is still in a beta version with regard to Jython support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible without any changes. Do it just like you would using the standard cpython. Create a virtualenv (pointing at Jython), install Flask, run your program.

```
virtualenv -p /opt/jython/bin/jython venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install Flask
```

`hello.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

```
FLASK_APP=hello.py FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run
```

When running in production, you do not want to use the dev server. Use an application server like Tomcat: [What's the best way to deploy a Flask app using Jython on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010517/whats-the-best-way-to-deploy-a-flask-app-using-jython-on-tomcat)