# is it possible to Deploy flask application to tomcat

Tags: java, python, tomcat7

I wrote a few python scripts that I would like to reuse in a java rest application and could not get execute the files with ProcessBuilder ( return not content from the getInputStream()) so I decided to create a Flask application to encapsulate the python scripts.. So my question is there a way to deploy a flask application to tomcat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010517/whats-the-best-way-to-deploy-a-flask-app-using-jython-on-tomcat

Comment: I took a look at that and created a simple flask app but couldn't get it to work... I believe I may be missing something but couldn't find additional post on it

Comment: I found another solution by using jython instead of flask.